# How to pass the Scala Map[String,Map[String,String]] to Js Object

Tags: javascript, scala, playframework

I wanted to pass the Scala Map values to JavaScript JSON onject in the Play framework view

I get "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 10 of the JSON data"  When I check the following code

```
val mapTobePassToJs = Map(

      "cg1" -> Map(
        "path" -> "/var/logs/cdr1/cdr",
        "name"  -> "CG-1"

      ),

      "cg2" -> Map(
        "path" -> "/var/logs/cdr2/cdr",
        "name"  -> "CG-2"
      ),

      "cg3" -> Map(
        "path" -> "/var/logs/cdr3/cdr",
        "name"  -> "CG-3"
      ),

      "cg4" -> Map(
        "path" -> "/var/logs/cdr3/cdr",
        "name"  -> "CG-4"
      )
    )

<script type="text/javascript">

        var aChartList = jQuery.parseJSON("@JSONObject(mapTobePassToJs).toString()".replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));

</script>
```

Anyone please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want Json as a result why are you not using `Json.obj()`. Following would be your structure then.

```
val mapTobePassToJs = Json.obj(

      "cg1" -> Json.obj(
        "path" -> "/var/logs/cdr1/cdr",
        "name"  -> "CG-1"

      ),

      "cg2" -> Json.obj(
        "path" -> "/var/logs/cdr2/cdr",
        "name"  -> "CG-2"
      ),

      "cg3" -> Json.obj(
        "path" -> "/var/logs/cdr3/cdr",
        "name"  -> "CG-3"
      ),

      "cg4" -> Json.obj(
        "path" -> "/var/logs/cdr3/cdr",
        "name"  -> "CG-4"
      )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions